# Multiple bundles in Parcel

Tags: typescript, bundling-and-minification, parceljs

I'm looking for a way to bundle multiple components in ParcelJS in the following format:

Input:

```
   -src 
   ----component1
   --------index.html
   --------main.ts
   --------class.ts

   ----component2
   --------index.html
   --------main.ts
   --------class.ts
```

Output:

```
   -dist
   ----component1
   --------index.html
   --------main.js

   ----component2
   --------index.html
   --------main.js
```

Is this possible? If so, can it be defined in a config file?

Comment: What solution did you end up going with?

Answer (score 0):

You can just run Parcel twice in succession. Assuming in each directory the `index.html` is your entry point you can do:

```
parcel src/component1/index.html && parcel src/component2/index.html
```